# Memory leak in Akka when using a scala stream

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have the following:

```
def iterator[T](name: String, stream: Stream[T])(handlers: Seq[Behavior[Option[T]]]) = {
    ActorSystem(Behaviors.setup[Option[T]] { context =>
        val actors = handlers.map(context.spawnAnonymous(_))
        context.spawnAnonymous(iterate(actors, stream))
        actors.foreach(_ ! None)
        Behavior.stopped
    }, name)
}

def iterate[T](actors: Seq[ActorRef[Option[T]]], s: Stream[T]): Behavior[Any] = s match {
    case h #:: t =>
        actors.foreach(_ ! Some(h))
        iterate(actors, t)
    case _ =>
        Behaviors.stopped
}
```

This will cause a memory leak with my stream members never getting freed. If I move the iterate call to outside of an actor behavior it works fine. I inspected my program with VisualVM and found the following is maintaining a reference to the head of the stream:

> factory$1inakka.actor.typed.internal.BehaviorImpl$DeferredBehavior$$anon$1#1

Is there a way I can do my iteration in a separate Behavior while ensuring my stream references are freed up?

Comment: From what I can see there is no point in trying to medel this iteration as an actor. You can just directly define `iterate` with `Unit` return type. And then there is that `Behavior.stopped` even for your `iterator` thing. What exactly are you trying to do here ? Just forget about actor and define your desired functionality.

Comment: This is just a use case to illustrate the issue. I need to do multiple iterations in parallel so it has to be done in an actor. The fact of the matter is there is a memory leak which I need to find a way of avoiding

Comment: An Actor never does anything in parallel. This code is so weird and pointless that it does not tell anything about whatever that "use-case" might be.